# Vuex state not updating on mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In my Vue.js/Vuex based application I'm using this mutation to reset part of the Vuex state:

```
restartGame(state) {
    state.gameRunning = true

    state.camera = {
        position: {
            x: 0,
            y: 10,
            z: 0
        },
        moveForward: false,
        moveBackward: false,
        moveLeft: false,
        moveRight: false,
        velocity: {
            x: 0,
            z: 0
        },
        mouseMovement: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        rotation: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
    }
}
```

This way, things work out fine, but writing out the whole camera state seems pretty verbose to me. So I extracted the initial camera state into a seperate file:

**initialCameraState.js**

```
export default {
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 10,
        z: 0
    },
    moveForward: false,
    moveBackward: false,
    moveLeft: false,
    moveRight: false,
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        z: 0
    },
    mouseMovement: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    rotation: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
}
```

I've refactored the `resetGame()` mutation like this:

```
import initialCameraState from './initialCameraState'

restartGame(state) {
    state.gameRunning = true

    state.camera = initialCameraState
}
```

But somehow this doesn't work, the Vuex store does not get updated but seems to just stay the same. How can this be?

I'm also using `initialCameraState.js` to set (part of) the initial state of the Vuex store. My first thought was that when mutating the according part of the state, `initialCameraState` is also being mutated. That would explain `resetGame()` not showing any effects. So I tried using the object spread operator in both places where `initialCameraState.js` gets imported/used, but this didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have all your code, but here's what I *think* may be happening. You are initing the game with the initial state which you have imported. During the game you update the state of the object by doing something like:

```
   state.camera['position'] = {
      x: 100,
      y: 100,
      z: 100
    }
  }
```

What actually happens is that your initial state has been updated because you have a reference to the object, not a copy of it, so when you try to reset the state it just remains the same, because you have inadvertently changed the initial state object.

To solve this simply wrap the initial state in a function (a factory function) so that the init state always gets returned:

```
export default function() {
  return {    
    position: {
      x: 0,
      y: 10,
      z: 0
    },
    moveForward: false,
    moveBackward: false,
    moveLeft: false,
    moveRight: false,
    velocity: {
      x: 0,
      z: 0
    },
    mouseMovement: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    rotation: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  }
};
```

Here's a JSFiddle showing what happens without a function (the positions remain the same): https://jsfiddle.net/9qg8ws0x/

And here one with the function (the positions are reset): https://jsfiddle.net/27xozazf/

Comment: Your solution works! But I'm still curious why using `camera: {...initialCameraState}` both for the initial state and the mutation didn't work. I thougt that using the object spread operator the values are getting copied, not referenced...

Comment: @lysigk Theoretically the spread operator should clone the object, it works fine with `Object.assign`:https://jsfiddle.net/jrqmvvsz/. So, honestly I'm not sure what is going on there

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
  initializeCamera () {
    return {
      position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 10,
        z: 0
      },
      moveForward: false,
      moveBackward: false,
      moveLeft: false,
      moveRight: false,
      velocity: {
        x: 0,
        z: 0
      },
      mouseMovement: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      rotation: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    }
  }
}

import initial from './initial'

restartGame(state) {
  state.gameRunning = true
  state.camera = initial.initializeCamera()
}
```